# How to loop through modules, link topics, and LTI links

Tags: desire2learn, lti

When we import content from our system to D2L, we create an LTI Link, a Quick Link given the LTI Link, and a Link Topic given the public URL from the Quick Link.  This is all good, a nice traceable chain and relationship.

Now, I am in need to pull this same information out.

I can see a GET to /orgId/content/root will give me modules.

I can see a GET to /orgId/content/modules/moduleId/structure will give a array which includes Link Topics and Modules (and recursively more of the same).

However, I am stuck on obtaining LTI Links for the Link Topics.  These are they 2 key abstractions for us.

I am further stuck on what exactly the Quick Link does for us.  There is no way to GET a Quick Link.

Now, going the other way, I can see a GET to /lti/link/orgId will get me all the LTI Links in the course.  But, there's no way to tell which Link Topic it's associated with.

Ditto for the Quick Link in this approach; I just don't know where this abstraction fits in.

Please advise.  Thanks dearly.

Answer (score 0):

A response has been posted in the Developer Community of Practice: https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/f_technical/how_to_loop_through_modules_link_topics_and_lti_links